# shell script construct array for file elements

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a file named input_file which contains some lines. I need to remove certain characters in the line and store them in an array. So to remove the characters, I use the sed command and storing in a variable as below.

```
            all_values=$(sed 's/^[^.]*\. //' < input_file)
            echo "$all_values"
```

It is working perfectly fine but I need `all_values` to be an array so that `all_values[0]` will contain the first line and `all_values[1]` the second line and so on.

Since I have a file, I do not know the total array elements before hand. How can I construct an array for my case?

EDIT:

My input file is like below.

```
This is first element
This is second element
Though spaces, I should be one element
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a bit more syntax to store the output in an array

```
all_values=( $(sed 's/^[^.]*\. //' < input_file) )
```

There will be trouble if any of the lines of output contain whitespace: each whitespace separated word will be a separate array element. Please show some sample input if that's the case.

---

```
all_values=()
while read -r line; do 
    all_values+=( "$line" )
done < <( sed 's/^[^.]*\. //' input_file )
```

Or, more tersely

```
mapfile -t all_values < <( sed 's/^[^.]*\. //' input_file )
```

`mapfile` is a bash built-in: see `help mapfile` from a bash prompt.

---

You don't even need sed for this. If I read your intention is to remove the first sentence from each line:

```
$ cat input_file 
Ignore me. keep me
Don't want this. Do want this

$ mapfile -t a < input_file 

$ shopt -s extglob

$ a=( "${a[@]#*([^.]). }" )

$ printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
keep me
Do want this
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I do have whitespaces. I will update the question with the sample input.

Comment: I have added the sample input to the question.